# Proof that joint-measurability means commutativity

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, quantum-information, statistics, quantum-measurements

For $i=1,2$, two measurements $m_{i}:\mathcal{X}_{i}\to\mathcal{L}(\mathcal{H})$, from alphabet $\mathcal{X}_{i}$ to set of bounded linear operators on Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$, are compatible or jointly measurable if they are marginals of a measurement $m:\mathcal{X}_{1}\times\mathcal{X}_{2}\to\mathcal{L}(\mathcal{H})$. The marginals are aquired by summing out $x\in\mathcal{X_{i}}$ for $m_{j}$ $j\neq i$. This is the sense in which joint measurability or compatibility is defined in the literature [1](https://arxiv.org/abs/1608.05614) ,[2](https://arxiv.org/abs/1908.10085). How does one prove commutativity of two jointly measurable observables?

Comment: Are you sure that the two measurements are on different Hilbert spaces? Because an operator on $H_1$ commutes with an operator on $H_2$ by definition. On a quick skim, I did not see anything about product spaces in the linked papers either.